# .NET 6 Stream reading breaking change or bug?

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, .net-6.0

I am currently upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6 and I came accross a breaking change or an odd behavior.

This is my code, that works perfectly in .NET Core 3.1:

```
public static byte[] Decrypt<SymmetricAlgorithmType>(byte[] securedData, SymmetricEncryptionOptions symetricEncryptionOptions)
    where SymmetricAlgorithmType : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{

    SymmetricAlgorithm symetric = new SymmetricAlgorithmType
    {
        Key = symetricEncryptionOptions.Key,
        IV = symetricEncryptionOptions.InitializationVector
    };

    byte[] bytes = new byte[securedData.Length];

    MemoryStream? memoryStream = new MemoryStream(securedData);
    CryptoStream encryptionStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, symetric.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    int realBytes = encryptionStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    encryptionStream.Close();
    byte[] realByteArray = new byte[realBytes];
    Array.Copy(bytes, realByteArray, realBytes);
    return realByteArray;

}
```

When running my unit test, with some sample data, the size of `securedData` is 32. The number of bytes actually read is 23 (also seen in the `realBytes` variable) and those are put into `realByteArray` of the correct size.

Running the exact same code in .NET 6, I now get 16 instead of 23, which crops the content.

So I thought, I rewrite the code to create a while loop that breaks until 0 bytes are read:

```
MemoryStream? memoryStream = new MemoryStream(securedData);
CryptoStream encryptionStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, symetric.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

byte[] buffer = new byte[securedData.Length];
int totalRead = 0;
while (totalRead < buffer.Length)
{
    int bytesRead = encryptionStream.Read(buffer, totalRead, 16);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    totalRead += bytesRead;
}
return buffer;
```

So on the first run, I get 16 bytes, the second run returns 7 bytes, but as soon as the loop runs the third time, I get the exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection. (Parameter 'count')'
```

The code seen above is according to the following article, where the breaking change in .NET 6 is mentioned:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/partial-byte-reads-in-streams

The only workaround I have so far is to read it byte by byte. So the same code, as seen above, but using: `1` instead of `16`: `encryptionStream.Read(buffer, totalRead, 1);`

Note that I use a `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged` as `SymmetricAlgorithm` with a 16 size byte array as key and also 16 size byte array as IV and the `CryptoStream` does not support `Seek` or `Slice`.

So I am wondering if this is a bug in .NET 6 or I am doing something totally wrong now, but was okay in .NET Core 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is yours.

The number of bytes returned from any `Read` call is an implementation detail - it just has to be *something* or *nothing* (EOF). So the number changing: is fine. The problem, however, is here:

```
int bytesRead = encryptionStream.Read(buffer, totalRead, 16);
```

The parameters still need to be valid, which they aren't *as you approach the end of the buffer*. Consider instead:

```
int bytesRead = encryptionStream.Read(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length - totalRead);
```

Now it always says "as much as you can, filling the buffer", rather than "read up to 16 bytes, regardless of how much space is left in the buffer".

Comment: I actually also had to add also the following, in order to have the right size of byte[] to be returned
   byte[] result = new byte[totalRead];
   Array.Copy(buffer, result, result.Length);
   return result;